How to use vite plugin $env or $lib alias in Svelte project
I'm using the Svelkit project.
When importing modules from Sveltkit, path aliases such as $lib and $env are often used.
However, when using a separate vite plugin that is not included within the Sveltkit project, I would like to use an alias such as $env or $lib used in the Sveltkit when importing environment variables or js files.
Below is what I tried, but it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?
vite.config.js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from 'path';
import socketHandler from './src/lib/server/socketHandler/socketHandler.js';

const webSocketServer = {
    name: 'webSocketServer',
    configureServer(server) {
        if (!server.httpServer) return;
        socketHandler(server.httpServer);
    }
}

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit() , webSocketServer()],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
              '$lib': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/lib'),
              '$env': path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
            },
          },
    
});

socketHandler.js
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import login from '$lib/login.js';
import {DB_PASSWORD} from '$env/static/private';
import disconnect from '$lib/disconnect.js';
// other imports...

global.userCode = {};

export default function socketHandler(server) {
    const db_pass=DB_PASSWORD;
    const io = new Server(server);

    const onConnection = (socket) => {

        reconnect(io, socket); 
        disconnect(io, socket);
        login(io, socket); 
        orderRequest(io, socket);
        // ...
    }
    
    io.on("connection", onConnection);
}

npm run dev
failed to load config from C:\home\lcare_renewal\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '$lib' imported from C:\home\lcare_renewal\vite.config.js.timestamp-1727503166699-f59eaa69482cd.mjs
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:890:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:939:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1132:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)


I've already tried this.
resolve: {
alias: [{ find: "$lib", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/lib") }],
},

To use $lib and $env aliases from Vite with standalone JavaScript files, you can use vite-node wrapped for node command.
See this answer for details.
Hope this gives you some good clues.
